# Duration of tasks with Windows Task scheduler

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to know the duration of a certain task to calculate from "Created Task Process" to "Task completed"?
Task scheduler only show the Last Run Time but not the duration of all execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
$TaskName = '\Task Name'
$StartTime = (Get-Date).Adddays(-7)
$EndTime = Get-Date
$filter = @{ LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational'
             ID = 129,102
             StartTime = $StartTime
             EndTime = $EndTime
             Data = $TaskName
          } 

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable $filter | Select-Object TimeCreated,@{n='Action';e={$_.TaskDisplayName}}
```

**Explanation:**

For `$TaskName`, you must enter the task name exactly as it would show in `(Get-WinEvent).Properties`. You can also see this exact name in the task history messages. It will likely contain the backslash in the name.

You can set `$StartTime` and `$EndTime` to whatever you like here. Having a time interval speeds up the query retrieval time.

`$filter` is where the magic happens. It will ultimately be pushed into the parameter `-FilterHashTable`. Since the `ID` key can accept an array of `[int]`, we can just comma separate the values. `129` is `Created Task Process`. `102` is `Task Completed`. `Data` does not accept wildcards so we must be exact with the task name as it would show in a `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty` property. If you do not use `Data`, you will have to rely on `Where-Object` to further filter your task data by the task name, which will be significantly slower.